# Creating Word docs with Python docx. Can you add hollow bullets with docx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I am creating a Word docs with Python docx. I can add regular bullets just fine but am trying to add the hollow bullets like these:

[image]

Instead of the regular bullets:

[image]

Here is how I add regular bullets (works fine):

```
paragraph_bullet = document.add_paragraph(style='List Bullet')
paragraph_bullet.paragraph_format.left_indent = Inches(1)
run = paragraph_bullet.add_run('The values under the columns, ')
```

In the [documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/python-docx/latest/python-docx.pdf) I see reference to:

[image]

But these bullet lists are not described and all produce the same standard black bullet.

Does anyone have any thoughts? I need to make this python generated Word document an exact match of the original, which has hollow bullets.

Comment: You will likely need to make a custom style for this.

Comment: looking that way. Thanks Kevin.

Comment: I am looking at the documentation but just cannot figure out how to approach this. So word has hollow bullets as an option. Can someone clue me on a high level perhaps how I might approach using docx to utilize these hollow bullets??